# What are "suites adjacentes" called in English?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, translation-request, mathematical-french

In French two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are called "suites adjacentes" iff:

- $(a_n)$ is decreasing
- $(b_n)$ is increasing
- $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n - b_n)$ = 0

A useful property is that both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are both convergent with the same limit and that   $(a_n) \geq (b_n)$ for all n.

What do we call "suites adjacentes" in English?

Comment: Can't say as I have ever heard the term, but they seem to be called "adjacent sequences", as one might guess.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139770/adjacent-sequences-example) for an example of the use of the term.

Comment: @lulu Ok - I guess I'll quote that then. How come in England this is not a common term?

Comment: Oh, some notions just don't get used often enough to gain widespread acceptance of their names.  In this instance...while a google search confirms that the term is indeed used in the way you'd like, I  personally wouldn't use it without defining it.  The definition is brief, after all, and, as I say, I wouldn't count on my readers knowing what the name meant.

Comment: Some, I answer with this fairly often, as it gives a satisfying picture  for limits;  similar to railroad trains heading towards each other on the same track, there is a point where they finally crash...we call this the limit...   If we write $H_n =  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$   and $ \log x$  the log based $e,$  we have lower sequence $b_n = H_n - \log n $   and upper $a_n =  H_{n+1}  - \log n$

Comment: If you reverse the rôles of $a_n$ and $b_n$, then this looks a lot like shrinking closed intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ with a unique point of intersection (cf. the "Nested Intervals Theorem"). I've never heard this term, however, in any language, and I'm not sure the terminology is very intuitive.

Comment: a lemma not in the question is:  for all $m,n$   we have $a_m \geq  b_n $

Comment: @WillJagy Yes the lemma is implied directly by the conditions. I have edited the question.

Comment: Some, you moved the phrase "and that   $(a_n) \geq (b_n)$ for all n."  What I had in mind  would say  "and that   $(a_n) \geq (b_m)$ for all $n,m.$"  My emphasis is that  each sequence element gives an upper or lower bound for the other sequence and for the limit.   Actually, I am not sure what you mean by placing $a_n$   in parantheses   as $(a_n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Si ce terme, comme certains autres, n'est pas courant dans les régions anglo-saxones, c'est parce que la France a une véritable tradition mathématique. Au fil des décennies, cette tradition-ci a mis au point son propre vocabulaire et sa propre approche -- par exemple dans l'intersection de l'algèbre et de la géométrie, car c'est là où Grothendieck et le groupe Bourbaki se sont brillamment distingués.*

The fact that this and quite a few other terms are not common in the Anglo-Saxon world is a product of the French mathematical tradition. Over the decades, this tradition has developed its own vocabulary and approach -- for instance in the intersection of algebra and geometry, where Grothendieck and the Bourbaki authors have made a huge mark.

*Il y a très peu de gens en dehors de la francophonie qui désireraient étudier les mathématiques en licence dans l'Hexagone. Donc, rien d'étonnant à ce que les connaissances de base soient enseignées en France sans égard pour la manière dont on en traite en Angleterre ou aux États-Unis.*

Very few people who are not from Francophone countries would want to do a Bachelor's degree in mathematics in France. It's no surprise, therefore, that they teach the basics there without any need to align with the way they do it in England or America.

Comment: Out of curiousity, are these your own thoughts and expressions? Are they held generally in France?