# Upper bound euler constant

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

Trying to show that the euler constant $\gamma \leq \frac{5}{6}$ .

I'm stuck in this, I was able to bound it with 1 after manipulation with integrals but it doesn't good enough.

then I tried this

$\gamma = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\:-ln\left(n\right)\right) =\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\sum _{k=2}^n\ln\left(k\right)-ln\left(k-1\right)\right)$
$= \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1+\sum _{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)\right)$

from here I tried to apply taylor series instead of $ln(\frac{k}{k-1})$
but again this doesn't lead anywhere, how can I bound it from above?

Comment: Have you had trouble expanding $ \ \ln\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right) \ $ as a Taylor series, or is it that you have done this but can't proceed further?

Comment: Can't proceed with that

Comment: How did you manipulate integrals to bound it by $1$? I suspect a slight modification will allow you to improve the bound.

Comment: Sorry I'm not from pc right now, I used the Theorem that sum from 2 to infinity is less or equal to integral from 1 to infinity and did it with integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ of $ln(n)$ which leaves me eith the first instance in the sum which is 1

Answer (score 3):

The function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is convex and decreasing. Hence, for $k \leqslant x \leqslant k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\frac{\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{x}}{k+1 - x}\leqslant \frac{\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+1}}{k+2 - k+1}$$

and, thus,

$$\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{x} \leqslant \left(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)(k+1-x)$$

Integrating over $[k,k+1]$ we get

$$\frac{1}{k+1} - \log \frac{k+1}{k} \leqslant  \left(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

Summing from $1$ to $m-1$ we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}  - \log m -1 \leqslant \frac{1}{2m+2} - \frac{1}{4}$$

Taking the limit of both sides as $m \to \infty$ yields

$$\gamma - 1 \leqslant -\frac{1}{4} \implies \gamma \leqslant 0.75 < \frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: Very elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_n^{n+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \;   g(n) \; < \; \int_{n-1}^n \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

Here is a diagram
[image]

Sum this  up from $n=a$ to $n=b.$
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{n=a}^b \;  g(n) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

With $g(x) = \log x$    we have

$$   \log(b+1) - \log a  < \; \sum_{n=a}^b \; \frac{1}{n} \; < \;  \log b - \log(a-1)  $$
Clearly we need to take $a>1.$   If we take $a=3$  the accuracy is good enough for your bound;
Here we imagine $b$  a large integer.

$$   \log(b+1) - \log 3  < \; \sum_{n=3}^b \; \frac{1}{n} \; < \;  \log b - \log 2  $$   and  so

$$ \frac{3}{2}  +  \log(b+1) - \log 3  < \; \sum_{n=1}^b \; \frac{1}{n} \; < \; \frac{3}{2}  +  \log b - \log 2  $$

Subtract $\log b$  to find

$$ \frac{3}{2}  +  \log(1 + \frac{1}{b}) - \log 3  < \; \left(\sum_{n=1}^b \; \frac{1}{n} \right) - \log b\; < \; \frac{3}{2}   - \log 2  $$

Letting $b$ grow without bound we find
$$ \frac{3}{2}     - \log 3  < \; \gamma \; < \; \frac{3}{2}   - \log 2  $$

If we had taken $a=4$  we would have found
$$ \frac{11}{6}     - \log 4  < \; \gamma \; < \; \frac{11}{6}   - \log 3  $$

It comes out
$$ H_n     - \log (1+n)  < \; \gamma \; < \; H_n   - \log n  $$
which is another satisfying approach: The expression $ H_n     - \log (1+n)$  starts low and increases as $n$ increases. The expression $ H_n     - \log n$  starts high and decreases as $n$ increases.  They crash together at $\gamma.$ See [What are "suites adjacentes" called in English?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391704/what-are-suites-adjacentes-called-in-english)

Answer (score 1):

One has the series expansion

$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots \quad \text{for $\ x\in(-1, 1]$.}$$

Since your limit is equal to the following,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k}} \ - \ \sum_{k=2}^n{\ln\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)} \right)}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k}} \ - \ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)} \right)}$$

we have that

$$\gamma \ = \ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k}} \ - \ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2k^2} + \frac{1}{3k^3} - \frac{1}{4k^4} + \dots\right)} \right)}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k}} \ - \ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)} \ + \ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{1}{3k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^4} - \dots\right)} \right)}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)} \ + \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{1}{3k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^4} - \dots\right)}$$

$$= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{1}{3k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^4} - \dots\right)}$$

Hence, one has the bound

$$\gamma \ \lt \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{1}{3k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^4}\right)} \ \lt \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{1}{4k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^4}\right)}$$

$$= \ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}} \ - \ \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{k^3} - \frac{1}{k^4}\right)}$$

$$\lt \ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}} - \frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2^3} \ - \ \frac{1}{2^4}\right) \ = \ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}} - \ \frac{1}{64}.$$

To bound the summation term, you can do the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}} = \ \left(1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \ \sum_{k=4}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}}\right)$$

$$= \ \left(\frac{49}{36} + \ \sum_{k=4}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}}\right) \ \lt \ \left(\frac{49}{36} \ + \ \sum_{k=4}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k(k-1)}}\right)$$

$$= \ \frac{49}{36} \ + \ \sum_{k=4}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}\right)}$$

$$= \ \left(\frac{49}{36} + \frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{61}{36}$$

Finally, we have

$$\gamma \ \lt \ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{61}{36} - \ \frac{1}{64} = \frac{479}{576}.$$

Indeed, integration would be an easier and much cleaner way to solve this problem, but the algebraic method still gives the desired result.